# Select value from different tables based on the column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a main table A with the following fields:

[image]

Then I have three separate tables, each for Buildings, Classrooms and Offices. All these tables have two columns; ID and Name.

I want to query the table A to get the following result:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: How could we possibly know what you want from this? Where do the other values come from? Is this as simple as needing a join? http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ That's my guess but it is hard to say. If that doesn't do it then you need to look here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Have a look at JOIN and InnerJoin :D http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data isn't really normalized.  Having three separate tables all serving the same lookup is causing you some headache... so I unioned the 3 tables together and created a 'src' column so you could join table A's type and Id back to table B's ID and src.  You'd have been better off having one table and non-repeating IDs and a type ID to specify if it's a building classroom or office.

```
Select * 
from A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'Building' as src, ID, Name FROM Buildings UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Classroom' as src, ID, Name FROM Classrooms UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Office' as src, ID, Name FROM Offices) B
on A.Location_Type = B.Src
and A.LocationID = B.ID
```

I used a left join here in case not all records in A have an associated record in B.  However, an inner join should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Should be doable with the use of a join.

Something along those lines should work:

```
SELECT tabelA.ID, tabelA.Subject, tabelA.Date, tabelA.locationType, tabelB.location
FROM tabelA INNER JOIN tabelB on tabelA.locationID = tabelB.locationID
```